Sharepoint list group header formatting on Approval Status (moderationStatus) column
I am trying to set up SharePoint list JSON group header formatting for the Approval Status column (also called 'moderationStatus' internally) but am unable to make it work. This column is system-created and used when content approval is enabled for the list.
I am using single-tier grouping and I have enabled COUNT aggregation for the 'Approval Status' column.
I have tested the JSON by grouping other columns and it works as expected.
Although the list is hosted on SharePoint I am using Microsoft lists modern experience (i.e. with ?env=WebViewList at the end of the URL)
Does anyone know if is possible to achieve this please? Thanks in advance.
JSON:
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "groupProps": {
        "headerFormatter": {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "padding-left": "12px",
                "font-size": "16px",
                "font-weight": "400",
                "cursor": "pointer",
                "outline": "0px",
                "white-space": "nowrap",
                "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
            },
            "customRowAction": {
                "action": "defaultClick"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                                "padding": "5px 5px 5px 5px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "@group.fieldData.displayValue"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "elmType": "div",
                            "style": {
                                "display": "flex",
                                "flex-direction": "row",
                                "justify-content": "center"
                            },
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "elmType": "div",
                                    "txtContent": "=' (' + @group.count + ')'"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


